# Why does my spring batch takes step2 while step1 is still going on?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-batch, aws-batch

First of all, thank you for checking out my post.
I would list the techs that are used, ​what I need to achieve and what is happening.

Services used:

- Spring Boot in Groovy
- AWS: AWS Batch, S3Bucket, SNS, Parameter Store, CloudFormation

What I need to achieve:

1. Read two csv files from S3 Bucket(student.csv: id,studentName are columns and score.csv: id,studentId,score)
2. Check who is failed by comparing two files. If student’s score is below 50, he/she is failed.
3. Create a new csv file in S3 Bucket and store it as failedStudents.csv.
4. Send an email via SNS topic the failedStudents.csv that was just created.

In the Spring Batch Config class, I am calling the 1,2,3 as step1 and 4 as step2.

```
@Bean
Step step1() {
    return this.stepBuilderFactory
                .get("step1")
                .<BadStudent, BadStudent>chunk(100)
                .reader(new IteratorItemReader<Student>(this.StudentLoader.Students.iterator()) as ItemReader<? extends BadStudent>)
                .processor(this.studentProcessor as ItemProcessor<? super BadStudent, ? extends BadStudent>)
                .writer(this.csvWriter())
                .build()
}

@Bean
Step step2() {
    return this.stepBuilderFactory
                .get("step2")
                .tasklet(new PublishSnsTopic())
                .build()
}

@Bean
Job job() {
    return this.jobBuilderFactory
                .get("scoring-students-batch")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(this.step1())
                .next(this.step2())
                .build()
}
```

ItemWriter

```
@Component
@EnableContextResourceLoader
class BadStudentWriter implements ItemWriter<BadStudent> {

    @Autowired
    ResourceLoader resourceLoader

    @Resource
    FileProperties fileProperties

    WritableResource resource

    PrintStream writer

    CSVPrinter csvPrinter

    @PostConstruct
    void setup() {
        this.resource = this.resourceLoader.getResource("s3://students/failedStudents.csv") as WritableResource
        this.writer = new PrintStream(this.resource.outputStream)
        this.csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(this.writer, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withDelimiter('|' as char).withHeader('id', 'studentsName', 'score'))
    }

    @Override
    void write(List<? extends BadStudent> items) throws Exception {
        this.csvPrinter.with {CSVPrinter csvPrinter ->
            items.each {BadStudent badStudent ->
                csvPrinter.printRecord(
                        badStudent.id,
                        badStudent.studentsName,
                        badStudent.score
                )
            }
        }
    }

    @AfterStep
    void aferStep() {
        this.csvPrinter.close()
    }
}
```

PublishSnsTopic

```
@Configuration
@Service
class PublishSnsTopic implements Tasklet {

    @Autowired
    ResourceLoader resourceLoader

    List<BadStudent> badStudents

    @Autowired
    FileProperties fileProperties

    @PostConstruct
    void setup() {

        String badStudentCSVFileName = "s3://students/failedStudents.csv"
        Reader badStudentReader = new InputStreamReader(
                this.resourceLoader.getResource(badStudentCSVFileName).inputStream
        )

        this.badStudnets = new CsvToBeanBuilder(badStudentReader)
                .withSeparator((char)'|')
                .withType(BadStudent)
                .withFieldAsNull(CSVReaderNullFieldIndicator.BOTH)
                .build()
                .parse()

        String messageBody = ""
        messageBody += this.badStudents.collect {it -> return "${it.id}"}

        SnsClient snsClient = SnsClient.builder().build()
        if(snsClient) {
            publishTopic(snsClient, messageBody, this.fileProperties.topicArn)
            snsClient.close()
        }
    }

    void publishTopic(SnsClient snsClient, String message, String arn) {
        try {
            PublishRequest request = PublishRequest.builder()
                                        .message(message)
                                        .topicArn(arn)
                                        .build()

            PublishResponse result = snsClient.publish(request)

        } catch (SnsException e) {
          log.error "SOMETHING WENT WRONG"
        }
    }

    @Override
    RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED
    }
}
```

The Issue here is that, while step 1 is executing step2 also gets executed.
And it would lead to serious problem as

1. As this batch job runs everyday. Let’s say today is Tuesday,  the `failedStudents.csv` is generated and stored fine. However while it is also running step2 instead of waiting for step1 to be done, step2 is send the `failedStudents.csv` that is generated on Monday. So csv is generated as new dataset. But Step2 is sending a day old students list.
2. For some reason, if `failedStudents.csv` is not stored in the s3 or turned into Glacier bucket, it would failed the batch job. Because in the Step2 it would crash due to FileNotFound Exception while Step1 is still going on and the `failedStudents.csv` is not created yet.

This is my first AWS and Spring Batch Project and so far, Step1 is working great perfectly. But I am guessing Step2 has a problem,

I appreciate reading my long post.
I would be very happy if anyone could answer or help me with this problem.
I have been fixing PublishSnsTopic and `ItemWriter`, but this is where I am stuck for a while, not sure how to figure this out.

Thank you so much again for reading.

Comment: Your `PublishSnsTopic` is wrong. The `@PostConstruct` gets run as soon as the job is instantiated so it runs directly. You shouldn't do all that stuff in an `@PostConstruct` annotated method, it should be in your `execute` method instead.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Thank you very much. I understand what you are saying. 
I had to use @PostConstruct because Autowired fields are not yet available to be used. I will do a bit more research about it. thank you so much again